# Unmasking SPI Interrupt for both TXE and RXNE on STM8S105

Tags: c, embedded, stm8

I am writing some firmware for an STM8S, and I want to have my SPI transmissions and receptions be handled in an ISR rather than polling.

According to pg. 284 of the  [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0016-stm8s-series-and-stm8af-series-8bit-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf), I should be able to set the SPI_ICR register to 0xC0 and have an interrupt triggered on both a SPI RXNE and TXE flag.

However, when I try and set this, it causes a fault and the device resets. Any idea why that is happening?

I have tried two methods:

The first is to use the STM8s SPL functions to set the register like this:

`SPI_ITConfig(SPI_IT_TXE,ENABLE); SPI_ITConfig(SPI_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);`

This works when I only set one one the interrupt sources, but when I do both it causes a fault. I read the code for this, and when you call both of them, it ends up just writing 0xC0 to the register.

I also tried directly setting the register like this:

`SPI->ICR |= 0xC0;`

This causes the exact same fault.

I can't get OpenOCD to work on my computer, so I am pretty much going blind here, but I can't figure it out, please let me know how I can fix this issue, or if it is just not possible to have both interrupts.

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably when you enable `TXE`, and you haven't actually sent anything yet, you'll immediately get an interrupt. Does your ISR cope with that?

Comment: @pmacfarlane That was the issue, I added a line to clear the TXE flag and it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Standard practice is usually to clear the status register just before enabling interrupts. Also, you must obviously have registered the relevant interrupt(s) in the vector table as well.

Comment: @Lundin Good to know, I added a line to clear the flags before enabling the interrupt.